# Performance difference in Concern method ran with Hook vs on Model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Basically I notice a big performance difference in dynamically overriding a getter for `ActiveRecord::Base` models within an `after_initialize` hook and simply within the model itself.

Say I have the following Concern:

```
module Greeter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_initialize { override_get_greeting }
  end

  def override_get_greeting
    self.class::COLS.each do |attr|
      self.class.class_eval do
        define_method attr do
          "Hello #{self[attr]}!"
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I then have the following model, consisting of a table with names.

```
CREATE TABLE 'names' ( 'name' varchar(10) );
INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ("John")
```

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  COLS = %w("name")
  include Greeter
end
```

```
john = Name.where(name: 'John').first
john.name # Hello John!
```

This works fine. However, if I try to do this a more *Rails* way it is significantly slower.

Essentially, I want to simply pass a parameter into `Greeter` method that contains `COLS` and then overrides the getters. It'll look something like:

```
# Greeter
module Greeter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def override_get_greeting(cols)
    cols.each do |attr|
      self.class.class_eval do
        define_method attr do
          "Hello #{self[attr]}!"
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

# Name
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Greeter
  override_get_greeting [:name]
end
```

Now `Name.where(name: 'John').first.name # Hello John!` is about 2 seconds slower on the first call.

I can't put my finger in it. I have an assumption that the the application is just slower to start with the first example, but not really sure.

I prefer the second example but the performance difference is a big no no.

Has anyone came across something like this?

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the real application code is **radically** different to what you've shown above, there's no way this should be causing a 2 second performance hit!

However, it's still a needlessly verbose and inefficient way to write the code: You're redefining methods on on the class instance, *every time you initialize the class*.

Instead of using `after_initialize`, you can just define the methods once. For example, you could put this in the `Greeter` module:

```
included do |klass|
  klass::COLS.each do |attr|
    define_method attr do                                  
      "Hello #{self[attr]}!"                               
    end
  end
end
```

Also worth noting is that instead of `self[attr]`, you may instead wish to use `super()`. The behaviour will be the same (assuming no other overrides are present), except that an error will be raised if the column does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the `super()` tip.
Are you suggesting to keep using constants instead? I would've preferred to have a method called that would trigger the getter overrides.

Comment: It won't make a difference performance-wise, but sure, use a method if you prefer.